# How to Load XML file into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, xml

EDITED QUESTION:

As per Jon SKeet's advice, I went with LINQ to XML. And come up with the below. Now How can I compare the LINQ object1 with object2.T The contents of test.xml is given below. test2.xml is just without last node being takeout from test.xml. How can i now compare these two LINQ objects system1 and system2

```
    XElement xelement1 = XElement.Load("C:\\test.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> system1 = xelement1.Elements();


XElement xelement2 = XElement.Load("C:\\test2.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> system2 = xelement2.Elements();


foreach (var config1 in system1)
{ 
      richTextBox1.AppendText("NAME: " + config1.Element("DisplayName").Value + Environment.NewLine );
      richTextBox1.AppendText("VERISON: " + config1.Element("DisplayVersion").Value + Environment.NewLine );
      richTextBox1.AppendText("DATE: " + config1.Element("InstallDate").Value + Environment.NewLine);
      richTextBox1.AppendText("PUBLISHER: " + config1.Element("Publisher").Value + Environment.NewLine);
      richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine); 
}



foreach (var config2 in system2)
{
    richTextBox2.AppendText("NAME: " + config2.Element("DisplayName").Value + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox2.AppendText("VERISON: " + config2.Element("DisplayVersion").Value + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox2.AppendText("DATE: " + config2.Element("InstallDate").Value + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox2.AppendText("PUBLISHER: " + config2.Element("Publisher").Value + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}


    <Software_List>
<Configuration>
<DisplayName>Adobe Reader X (10.1.10)</DisplayName> 
<DisplayVersion>10.1.10</DisplayVersion> 
<InstallDate>20140630</InstallDate> 
<Publisher>Adobe Systems Incorporated</Publisher>
</Configuration>
<Configuration>
<DisplayName>Adobe Shockwave Player 12.1</DisplayName> 
<DisplayVersion>12.1.3.153</DisplayVersion> 
<InstallDate>20140714</InstallDate> 
<Publisher>Adobe Systems, Inc</Publisher>
</Configuration>
<Configuration>
<DisplayName>Citrix Receiver</DisplayName> 
<DisplayVersion>14.1.0.0</DisplayVersion> 
 <InstallDate></InstallDate> 
<Publisher>Citrix Systems, Inc.</Publisher>
</Configuration>
</Software_List>
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument? This sort of thing is simpler with LINQ to XML...

Comment: Additionally, your requirements aren't really clear... what do you expect the dictionary key/values to be? ("Publisher") doesn't make much sense, as there are multiple publisher tags... Are you even sure you need a dictionary, rather than a LINQ join?

Comment: I am not sure.. That is my problem. I have multiple values for DisplayName,DisplayVersion,InstallDate and Publisher. I am trying to find if every DisplayName from XML1 does exist in XML2, if found then check other properties like DisplayVersion,InstallDate and Publisher for that matched record.

Comment: So that sounds like you basically want to join on DisplayName. You may well find this easier to think about if you create a `Configuration` class, and load each XML document as a `List<Configuration>`. Then you can take the XML out of the picture, and just concentrate on the objects...

Comment: Exactly Jon.. Can you please show me a sample code for that. I am completely new to OOPS and programming. How do I do..
Can you help me please.. Am i doing it correctly
`code`class Configuration
{
private string _name;
private string _version;
private string _date;
private string _pub;
}

public int DisplayName
{
    get { return _name; }set {_name=value; }
}
public string DisplayVersion
{
    get { return _version; } set { _version=value; }
}
public string Installdate
{
    get { return _date; } set { _date=value; }
}
public int Publisher
{
    get { return _pub; } set { _pub=value; }
}`code`

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Put it in your *question* - and learn about automatically implemented properties, which will make the code *much* simpler. At that point, your question really isn't about dictionaries at all - it's about loading an object from XML. I suggest you read LINQ to XML tutorials and search for similar questions.

Comment: Since I am beginner, I feel LINQ is complex and confusing. Would you be able to help me with this approach..?

Comment: You should do the research first. Read a LINQ to XML tutorial, and ask *specific* questions. Stack Overflow isn't an interactive tutorial, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is Jon SKeet not Jon Sleet.